# Unhashable type "slice" when trying to plot Random Forest

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to plot my Random Forest, but it gives me the following error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' in addition to displaying empty plots. The model itself works fine, giving me acceptable precision and recall scores.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, random_state=0) 
forest.fit(train_x, train_y) 

import matplotlib as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mglearn

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(20, 10))
for i, (ax, tree) in enumerate(zip(axes.ravel(), forest.estimators_)):
    ax.set_title("Tree {}".format(i))
    mglearn.plots.plot_tree_partition(train_x, train_y, tree, ax=ax)

mglearn.plots.plot_2d_separator(forest, train_x, fill=True, ax=axes[-1, -1],
                                alpha=.4)
axes[-1, -1].set_title("Random Forest")
mglearn.discrete_scatter(train_x[:, 0], train_x[:, 1], train_y)
```

See detailed error below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-26f28abf17a0> in <module>()
      2 for i, (ax, tree) in enumerate(zip(axes.ravel(), forest.estimators_)):
      3     ax.set_title("Tree {}".format(i))
----> 4     mglearn.plots.plot_tree_partition(train_x, train_y, tree, ax=ax)
      5 
      6 mglearn.plots.plot_2d_separator(forest, train_x, fill=True, ax=axes[-1, -1],

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mglearn\plot_interactive_tree.py in plot_tree_partition(X, y, tree, ax)
     65     eps = X.std() / 2.
     66 
---> 67     x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - eps, X[:, 0].max() + eps
     68     y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - eps, X[:, 1].max() + eps
     69     xx = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 1000)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2137             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2138         else:
-> 2139             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2140 
   2141     def _getitem_column(self, key):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2144         # get column
   2145         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2146             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2147 
   2148         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1838         """Return the cached item, item represents a label indexer."""
   1839         cache = self._item_cache
-> 1840         res = cache.get(item)
   1841         if res is None:
   1842             values = self._data.get(item)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

[image: train_x]

[image: train_y]

Comment: Since you get an error from mglearn or pandas here you need to make sure your question is tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from pandas because the function doesn't support it

Try replacing your dataframe `train_x` with `train_x.values` in your `plot_2d_separator`

Hope this helps,
Cheers

Comment: I changed it and now the error is different: KeyError: 'figure.constrained_layout.use'

Comment: Can you provide me with the dataset you're using and its shape ?

Comment: Also the full error that you are getting so I can reproduce it locally, because I tried your code on a toy dataset and it works :)

Comment: Hi Manar! I added pictures of train_y and train_x to the question. They are basically in a pandas dataframe. :) I am running it in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Hmmm i just reran it and got a new error: IndexError: too many indices for array...but the first plot displays something...the others are empty. I guess that is some progress

Comment: Just make sure that you transform your 'train_x' and 'train_y' into numpy arrays and that 'train_x' has only 2 columns